# Print several documents when click button django

Tags: python, html, django, printing

My question is about how to select several documents and print those documents. For example, I choose 3 documents and when I click print button, they will be open in new link and all documents must be on one page.
And top of this page I will have print button. Each document I can get by unique doc_id, and sent document data in json format, I already wrote function to print single document, but I don't know how to open several documents on one page, it must be same?

[image: prine several documents]

[image: print button on the top]

**code to print single document:**

```
def view_signed_document(request, code):
    params = dict()
    try:
        obj = DownloadCode.objects.get(code=code)
    except:
        return render(request, 'documents/doc_not_found.html', {'code': code})
    params['Docs'] = docs
    params['pb'] = pb
    params['is_pdf'] = request.GET.get('is_pdf', 'false')
    params['code'] = code
    params['host'] = request.scheme + "://" + request.META["HTTP_HOST"]
    params['url'] = settings.SITE_URL + request.get_full_path()

    if obj.doc_type == INVOICE_TYPE:
        # Invoice proxy has different parameter names, therefore we handle it
        # in separate case.
        response = proxy.get_invoice_by_id(invoice_id=obj.doc_id, tin=obj.tin)
        if response.status.code != pb.ResponseStatus.OK:
            response = proxy.get_invoice_draft_by_id(
                invoice_draft_id=obj.doc_id, tin=obj.tin)
        params['invoice'] = response.invoice
        template = 'pdf/invoice.html'
    else:
        ref = perm.document_type_proxy[obj.doc_type]
        response = ref['get'](doc_id=obj.doc_id, tin=obj.tin)
        if response.status.code != pb.ResponseStatus.OK:
            return render(request, 'documents/doc_not_found.html', {'code': code})
        params['document'] = response.document
        params['sign_actions'] = sum(
            x.permission == docs.SIGN for x in response.document.document_actions)
        template = ref['print_template']
        if obj.doc_type == COMMONS_TYPE:
            if response.document.internal_type == docs.CommonDocument.WITH_FILES:
                template = ref['print_files_template']
    return render(request, template, params)
```

Comment: show your efforts, what you have done so far @BakhtiyarBekbergen

Comment: @Sanket see code above